# Solving trigonometric equation $-2\csc^2 x\cot x=2\csc x$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm having a serious brain lag and can't figure out how to solve this equation:

$$-2\csc^2 x\cot x=2\csc x$$

My initial thoughts was that it could be a quadratic in disguise, but that doesn't seem to be it. How do I solve it?

Comment: $\frac{-2}{sin^2x}\cdot \frac{cosx}{sinx}=\frac{2}{sinx}$?

Comment: $-2\csc x(\csc x.\cot x+1)=0$ then?

Answer (score 2):

It *is* a quadratic in disguise.

Since $\csc x$ is never $0$, we can "cancel" and arrive at the equation $\csc x\cot x=-1$. In terms of the more familiar sines and cosines, we have the equation 
$$\frac{1}{\sin x} \cdot\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}=-1.$$
This is equivalent to $\cos x=-\sin^2 x$. Replace $-\sin^2 x$ by $\cos^2 x-1$. We end up with the quadratic equation $\cos^2 x-\cos x-1=0$ in $\cos x$. The Golden Number strikes again.

Comment: So using the quadratic formula you'd get
$cosx=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}{2}$ but then you can't solve for x..? I've done something stupid...

Comment: You would get $\cos x=\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. (The other root is rejected because it is $\gt 1$ so cannot be the cosine of any real $x$.)  If you are getting an unexpected result, perhaps the initial equation is not the "right" one.

Comment: The answer says $x=-\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{3\pi}{4}$. When I do $cos^{-1}(\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2})$ I don't get either of those values. Could the answer be wrong?

Comment: You may have quoted the **question** incorrectly. Plug in $x=-\pi/4$. On the left we get $-2(2)(-1)$ and on the right we get $2(-\sqrt{2})$. They are not equal.

Comment: Hmm, I may have been really stupid then. Question:
$f(x)=csc^2x$, $f'(x)=-2csc^2xcotx$
Solve

$f'(x)=2f(x)$ for $-\pi<x<\pi$

Comment: Then the equation is $-2\csc^2 x\cot x=2\csc^2 x$, which simplifies to $\cot x=-1$. That makes the answer right.

Comment: wow. I missed the squared and we went on a massive detour... I'm an idiot. But thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome.